# Where is plist preference file path located for FileMaker Pro Advanced 14?

Tags: filemaker

Some days ago I loose the plist items containing the custom functions for Data Viewer and while recovering the right file from backup I realised that my FileMaker Pro Advanced 14 application is using plist preferences named "com.filemaker.client.advanced12.plist"!
How is it possible?

Where may I reset the right path to the "com.filemaker.client.advanced14.plist"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileMaker is using the "com.FileMaker.client.advanced12.plist" preference file for all versions from 12 and onwards.

Comment: FileMaker is not aware of this, you mean?
https://support.filemaker.com/s/answerview?language=en_US&anum=15074

Comment: I remember doing this conversion myself actually, but I believe they now use only the version 12 plist file. I have all versions on my machines,but only one (12) plist file. You could rename your version 14 file to 12 and it should give you back your data viewer functions, if they are there.

Comment: Thanks AndreasT! Glad to know I am not alone ;-)